# Rspec target a specific link in xpath where link text is a piece of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, rspec

I'm a bit new to this but I'm trying to get rspec to click on a link. 
I've replaced the 'Show' link on an index pager with a link which is the name of the item.

i.e. My view has this

```
     <td><%= link_to task.name, task_path(task) %></td>
```

My rspec file had a reference

```
    find(:xpath, "(//a[text()= 'Show'])[1]").click
```

which I want to turn into something like

```
    find(:xpath, "(//a[text()= @task1.name])[1]").click
```

That should pick up the correct task in the list so I can follow it with

```
    it { should have_content(@client.name) }
    it { should have_content(@task1.name) }
    it { should have_content(@task1.description) }
```

Unfortunately I can't work out how to put that @task.name in so that it doesn't break.

Any ideas?

Update:

```
    Failure/Error: find(:xpath, "(//a[text()= @task1.name])[1]").click
    Capybara::ElementNotFound:
    Unable to find xpath "(//a[text()= @task1.name])[1]"
    # ./spec/requests/task_pages_spec.rb:123:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: post the error message and the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was much easier than I thought....

```
    click_link @task1.name
```

Think I might need to go and cry in the corner for a bit having spent hours trying to work that one out...

Answer (score 0):

Please try your `xpath` this way,you missed the Ruby's **string interpolation**:

```
find(:xpath, "//a[text()= \"#{@task1.name}\"][1]").click
```

I tried to produce a similar example :-

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-eotl
<div>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>foo</p>
  <p>bar</p>
</div>
eotl

doc.class # => Nokogiri::HTML::Document

class Person
  attr_accessor :name
end

ram = Person.new
ram.name="foo"
ram.name # => "foo"
doc.search("//div/p[text()= \"#{ram.name}\"]").to_a.size
# => 2
```

Comment: Failure/Error: find(:xpath, "(//a[text()= #{@task1.name}][1]").click
     Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError:
       Invalid predicate: (//a[text()= New Task1][1]
     # ./spec/requests/task_pages_spec.rb:124:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'